# Bluetooth Low Energy Android Server

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently playing wiht Bluetooth Low Energy for android 4.3, don't have BLE beacons at the moment, so my idea is to user one android 4.3 as BLE server. But there is quite good explanation how to create client app

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#close

and almost nothing about server, except this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattServer.html

Is there are some tutorials or examples?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you some examples for Android but if you have a developer license and an iOS Device you could use estimotes Brodcaster example.  
[> Estimote Beacon Demo](https://github.com/Estimote/beacons-demo)

At the moment I'm playing around with BLE on Android as well and use this App on an iOS Device to emulate a beacon.

Comment: I found an example App for Android. Maybe this can be helpful. [BLE Sample](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/)

Comment: Did you find any example?  I am looking for a solution to use a samsung galaxy s3 as a server and note 3 as a client. A sinple client server example would be greate.

Answer (score 3):

I found those very useful:
https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples

For the server parh check out this example:
https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/tree/master/BluetoothGattPeripheral